# QTableWidget set the Background of header Cell

Tags: qt, python-2.7, pyqt, qtstylesheets

I know how to set the Horizontal Headers background color, but how can i set the Headers Background Color for a specified Row? In this example, say i want to have the Header Row with the Label **"3"** to be red?

[image]

The above screenshots code:

```
import sys
from PyQt4 import QtCore, QtGui
from PyQt4.QtGui import *



class Example(QtGui.QWidget):

    def __init__(self):
        super(Example, self).__init__()
        self.initUI()


    def initUI(self):
        self.setGeometry(300, 300, 250, 150)
        self.rigTable = QTableWidget(1, 3, self)
        style = "::section {""background-color: lightblue; }"
        self.rigTable.horizontalHeader().setStyleSheet(style)
        self.rigTable.setShowGrid(False)

        self.rigTable.setCellWidget(0, 0, QLabel("A"))
        self.rigTable.setCellWidget(0, 1,  QLabel("B"))      

        self.show()


def main():
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    ex = Example()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [QTableWidgetItem](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qtablewidgetitem.html) class:

```
header = QtGui.QTableWidgetItem("3")
header.setBackground(QtGui.QColor("red"))
self.rigTable.setHorizontalHeaderItem(2, header)
```

Comment: did you run your code? For me its still not getting red

Comment: you're right, the stylesheet overwrite the single color definition